# Video dataset for abnormal event detection in bank ATM?

Tags: data-request

I am doing a project in abnormal event detection in ATM counters. I googled but couldn't find any video dataset for ATM counters. For training purposes, I need videos from people behaving 'normally' in ATM counters and from people showing abnormal behavior.

With *ATM counter* I mean a (small) room with one or more ATM machines built in a wall.

Normal event: A person walks into the room, puts his card into the ATM, enters pincode, retrieves his card, take his money, maybe a receipt, then leaves.

Abnormal events: Someone hitting the ATM, attacking and robbing a customer at an ATM, fiddling with the machine in unexpected ways, taking photographs inside, etc.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have edited the question

Comment: did u get any help?